# Javascript: Count number of table rows for each table and return a value to corresponding elements

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have three tables on a web page. Each table has a corresponding element nested in `<thead>` tags that I need to reflect the number of rows in its respective table, minus the head row and bottom row (-2). When I'm working with a single table, this code works just fine:

HTML Table Snippet:

```
<table class="table" id="category">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i> headache - <label class="label label-primary" id="tableBadge">0</span></th>
              <th><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Date Added</th>
              <th><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Options</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>Test entry</td>
              <td>1/19/2016</td>
              <td>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> add entry</a></td>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Javascript:

```
function catCount() {
    var rows = document.getElementById("category").rows.length;
    document.getElementById("tableBadge").innerHTML = rows - 2 + " entries";
}
```

However, respecting the laws of HTML in that ID's are unique to an element, I'm left in a bind. Using `getElementsByClassName()` or `getElementsByTagName()`  the values return 0, telling me it's not working. At least using identical syntax.

I've searched Google et al. for a solution, but they seem to be tailored towards the total amount of rows, rather individual counts respective of their tables.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show a complete `<table>` you're working with?

Comment: Updated as requested.

Comment: Does the count change dynamically, and in response to what? Or does it remain the same throughout the 'life' of the page?

Comment: The idea is that when a new entry is created, the count will increase on page reload. I'm not too concerned with a "live update" as it were.

Comment: In the table you show the 'count' (presumably in the element `#tablebadge`) should be 0, or should be 1? Effectively I'm asking which rows should be discounted from the count, and which should be counted? Which do you consider the 'heading' and which the 'footer'? Given that you're using `thead` and `tbody`, why not use `tfoot` as well, to clearly contain the rows that you don't want to count?

Comment: I see what you're getting at. The `<thead>` and final `<td>` element are excluded. What I did to offset, was to simply subtract 2 from the final result. The number 0 is just a number I placed there as a default value that will, if the script works correctly, change to the correct number on page load.

Yes, you are correct about the `#tablebadge` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change id tableBadge to tableBadge_category and similar to othter tables.

'*table_id*' is a id of table and you span is tableBadge_*table_id*

```
function catCount(table_id) {
    var rows = document.getElementById(table_id).rows.length;
    document.getElementById("tableBadge_"+table_id).innerHTML = rows - 2 + " entries";
}


catCount('category');
catCount('other_table');
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: I’d suggest a slight modification – do not get the `rows.length` of the table element itself, but of the tbody element instead, `document.getElementById(table_id).tBodies[0].rows.length`, _and_ put the “bottom row” (which seems to have a special meaning anyway, and can not be considered a normal “entry” as the previous rows are) into the `tfoot` element – then you don’t have to subtract the “magic number” 2, meaning you would not have to adapt the code should another table row be added to the thead.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Thank you very much for your input and to Cuchu for helping me out.

Comment: option to count rows: var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;

Answer (score 0):

Try instead using the `querySelectorAll` like:

`document.querySelectorAll('.table>thead>tr')`

The length of the array may be the answer you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByTagName and getElementsByClassNAme return node list, you need to iterate over them.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    //This is a node list you must iterate
    var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');

    for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        //This loop will handle each tble selected
        var table = tables[i];
        var totalRows = table.rows.length;
        console.log(totalRows);
        //Add your code here
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer, I'd suggest that the following might be slightly more useful, and far less-reliant on hard-coding exemptions (and therefore less of a maintenance nightmare for the future).

That said, my solution involves placing the 'footer' inside of a `<tfoot>` element, in order that the relevant `<tr>` elements are all contained within the `<tbody>` element(s) of the `<table>`.

The JavaScript function I'd recommend:

```
// wrapping the function in an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression
// ("IIFE") in order that it runs immediately and does not require
// calling later:
(function() {

  // using 'let' (rather than var) to declare local variables, all
  // of which are available only within the block in which they're
  // declared; here we convert the NodeList returned by
  // document.querySelectorAll('span.label') into an Array, using
  // Array.from():
  let outputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span.label')),

  // declaring another variable for later use:
    tbodies;

  // iterating over each of the found 'span.label' elements
  // in the Array, using Array.prototype.forEach():
  outputs.forEach(function(span) {
    // the first argument (here 'span') is the current
    // array-element of the array over which we're iterating.

    // finding the closest ancestor <table> element from the
    // current span node, and then finding all the <tbody>
    // elements contained within that <table>, and converting
    // that NodeList to an Array, again using Array.from() to
    // do so:
    tbodies = Array.from(span.closest('table').querySelectorAll('tbody'));

    // updating the text-content of the span to:
    // the sum of the child <tr> elements found in each of
    // the <tbody> elements found within the <table>, using
    // Array.prototype.reduce() to reduce the Array to a single
    // (here numeric) value; here we use an Arrow Function
    // to add the number of children of the <tbody> element
    // to the initialValue of the reduce method (0, the
    // final argument following the comma):
    span.textContent = tbodies.reduce((initialValue, tbody) => a + tbody.children.length, 0);
  });

// here the function is invoked:
})();
```

```js
(function() {
  let outputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span.label')),
    tbodies;

  outputs.forEach(function(span) {
    tbodies = Array.from(span.closest('table').querySelectorAll('tbody'));

    span.textContent = tbodies.reduce((initialValue, tbody) => initialValue + tbody.children.length, 0);
  });

})();
```

```html
<table class="table category">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i> headache - <span class="label label-primary"></span>
      </th>
      <th><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Date Added</th>
      <th><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> add entry</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test entry</td>
      <td>1/19/2016</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9ogohm2a/).

It's worth noting that the above approach will handle multiple `<table>` elements each with, potentially, multiple `<tbody>` elements; and requires no hard-coding of values to discount from the final count, since it selects only those elements that *should* be counted.

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
- [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).